# Missing right parenthesis error in Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE Countries
    (CountryID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CountryName VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    RegionID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Regions(RegionID)
    );
```

keeps throwing me this:
`ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inline foreign key syntax does not take a `FOREIGN KEY` keyword.

Consider:

```
CREATE TABLE Countries (
    CountryID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CountryName VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    RegionID INT REFERENCES Regions(RegionID)
);
```

Alternatively, you can declare the foreign key on another line, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Countries (
    CountryID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CountryName VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    RegionID INT,
    CONSTRAINT fkRegionID FOREIGN KEY (RegionID) REFERENCES Regions(RegionID)
);
```

This works as well:

```
CREATE TABLE Countries (
    CountryID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CountryName VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    RegionID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (RegionID) REFERENCES Regions(RegionID)
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3350902d5f03d3a53c94fc2447c06b6d)**